# Null pointer exception when trying to implement spinner in Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, spinner

```
static final String[] Build_Options = new String[]
    {"A","B","C"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.Mapp);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

      //InputStream is = mydbconnect();
   // InputStream is2 =mydbconnect2();

   // JSONArray jArray = getJSONobj(is);
   // JSONArray jArray2 = getJSONobj(is2); => Not relevant to this part of the code.


    Button alert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HelloGoogleMap.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Build_Options);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    System.out.println("YESS!!!!!!");

    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HelloGoogleMap.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,List <String> spinnerArray);


    System.out.println("TEST");
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    System.out.println("PASS");
```

---

The error that is return is as follows:

```
07-24 06:13:01.607: D/dalvikvm(959): GC freed 3589 objects / 247552 bytes in 117ms
07-24 06:13:02.577: D/dalvikvm(959): GC freed 2994 objects / 200040 bytes in 107ms
07-24 06:13:03.277: D/dalvikvm(959): GC freed 3838 objects / 262184 bytes in 144ms
07-24 06:13:03.346: I/System.out(959): YESS!!!!!!
07-24 06:13:03.357: I/System.out(959): NOOOOO!!!!
07-24 06:13:03.357: D/AndroidRuntime(959): Shutting down VM
07-24 06:13:03.357: W/dalvikvm(959): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
07-24 06:13:03.357: E/AndroidRuntime(959): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hellogooglemap/com.example.hellogooglemap.HelloGoogleMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at com.example.hellogooglemap.HelloGoogleMap.onCreate(HelloGoogleMap.java:85)
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
07-24 06:13:03.376: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  ... 11 more
07-24 06:13:03.406: I/dalvikvm(959): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
07-24 06:13:03.477: I/dalvikvm(959): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-24 06:18:03.446: I/Process(959): Sending signal. PID: 959 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Are you sure your spinner in main.xml is id'd by spinner1?

Comment: make sure to import R of your package's name.

Comment: HelloGoogleMap.java:85...please paste line No 85 of HelloGoogleMap.java

Comment: And where have you printed this No from 07-24 06:13:03.357: I/System.out(959): NOOOOO!!!!
It's not seen in the code you have placed here

Comment: Your spinner is null. Check if you have imported your package's R. Or the main.xml might not have ur spinner.

Comment: Your onCreate() is not complete and thus we cannot see where the error is. Please post all the function.

Answer (score 0):

Which line is line 85?

Probably your `spinner` is null, check the view id.